# Pre-authentication steps in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, hook, ejabberd, whatsapp

I am working on a project like whatsapp and using ejabberd as a backend server with Android/IOS clients. I want to do some whatsapp like step-
1. Client sends mobile number to server.
2. server sends OTP in return to the client and starts a timer say 2 minutes.
3. If client sends correct OTP, received from the server, to the server within the time specified. Client will be registerd.

I need help in which ejabberd module should I write the code of above steps. I know, to modify Ejabberd I can use Hooks and IQ handlers, but they can be used once the user is already registered. Right?

Should I use other language server, just for the above steps? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write new ejabberd module which starts a new SSL server on a specific port. Do your authentication on that.

If you are familiar with ejabberd's core, you can add your own module in `listen` part of config and write new module as backend of your server (same as ejabberd itself which wrote `ejabberd_c2s`, `ejabberd_service`, etc).
I just read its code and i recommend to read the code too.
For example in ejabberd version 17.01 [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/17.01/src/ejabberd_listener.erl#L52) reads config and runs a tcp server for every section of `listen` key. every section has three parts Port, Module and Opts. For xmpp clients of ejabberd these are 5222, `ejabberd_c2s` and Opts is other values. in [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/17.01/src/ejabberd_listener.erl#L343) for every accepted connection it calls `ejabberd_socket:start(Module, gen_tcp, Sock, Opts)`. In `ejabberd_socket:start/4` [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/17.01/src/ejabberd_socket.erl#L93) starts a process say A for receiving from socket and parsing XML and send them to another process say B and [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/17.01/src/ejabberd_socket.erl#L102) starts a process (B) from `ejabberd_c2s`. Process B receives XMLs from Process A and does all actions off XMPP clients in ejabberd.

Comment: Can you provide some book reference or blog or sample code for the same?

Comment: Awesome. Now I understands the server side changes for customization. But how to connect with this custom module from client side before registering the account(the OTP thing)? AFAIK,  Smack/Asmack lib. need login credentials before using communication with the server.

Comment: You have to use 2 ports. one for registering and one for registered users. registered users should connect to normal erjabbrd_c2s on port 5222 and new users have to connect to your module at your port.

Comment: @Poriya, please help me in writing a basic module for registering user. I want user send request = "A" and in return get "B" in Ejabberd. I can extend from here. I will use Sockets in Java to make the request. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Shubham1164 https://gist.github.com/Pouriya-Jahanbakhsh/f4484223e7333bf5709fc726cebd8db4

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a restful service to do this.

Please consider following steps:

1. Client sends mobile number to restful service.
2. The restful service create a OTP and save it in Redis with expired is set.
3. The client sends OTP to restful service. If the OTP is correct, service sends a jwt Token to client and save it in Redis with expired is set.
4. The client sends jwt token to eJabberd server and the server authenticates with `ejabberd_auth_jwt` module.

This may meet your requirement.